# How to create async for loops?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, parallel-processing, jruby

Is it possible to make a for loop divided asynchronous? That each iteration will be calculated in parallel to speed up the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) for that:

```
Parallel.each(elements) { |element| do_something(element) }
```

You can also control the number of threads (with the `in_threads:` keyword). If you need true parallelism, you can also specify the number of processes (with the `in_processes:` keyword).